# Query about Split() function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, split

So here is the thing, I have a variable with the list data

```
[('https://jira.corp.***.com/browse/DE-3872',), ('https://jira.corp.***.com/browse/DE-3839',)].
```

I'm basically using `split()` to get the last ID ( DE-3872.. etc)

If I do this ,

```
for link in data:
    issue = data[0][0].split('/')[4]
    print(issue)
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
DE-3872
DE-3872
```

It prints the first value twice, but what I'm trying to get is ,

```
DE-3872
DE-3839
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the same thing twice, use:

```
for link in data:
    issue = link[0].split('/')[-1]
    print(issue)
```

The `[-1]` index will return the last part of the result.